# Mobile Web or Mobile App?

Tags: android-emulator, dojo

We are building a webapp combining dojo and couple of other GIS related frameworks to render map and other data to browser. It works perfectly fine in desktop browser (firefox, chrome). However when we fire it up an andriod emulator, the performance is very slow. we have increased the memory to about 2 GB and VM around 256mb for the emulator.

What could the problem be?

Is it better to develop a seperate android app or continue this as a mobile web itself?

Answer (score 0):

Basically your question relies on the same effect as to what happened to facebook.
Their original "app" was based on HTML5 development and was slow as molasses. They realized that if they went native - their performance would increase. In reality it was slapping on rocket launchers.

It would be the same for android and android apps.

If you have built it as a web app it will be pulling request and then rendering it as html as if it was an open browser rather than using the native map applications built into the system.

If you are savvy enough and your code is more JS than anything with the dojo framework look into the Titanium Framework Accelerator to translate your native web code into a native app. Though tweaking will be needed in order to call native API map protocols

http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-platform/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I dont want to change my framework. If I want to make my web app mobile compatible then is it ok to use the mobile dojo version?

Answer (score 0):

Android simulator is slow, it's better if you test in real devices.

Anyway if performance is a must, you should develop a native app. HTML5 is improving but in some situations you need native code. Or if your code is mainly Javascript, there are some javascript compilers to generate native code and improve the performance.